# Can I specify the color of a service's log prefix in my docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-stack, docker-logs

I have five services, which all get assigned a random color on docker-compose up at the moment. The problem is, one color is the exact same color as the background of powershell, which I use to up the services. Can I assign a color to each service in my docker-compose?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [old issue requesting this feature](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4269) in docker-compose, which was (unfortunately?) rejected.

If the main issue is that the color clashes with your background, you could use the `--no-color` option to get a monochrome output. It's not great, but at least it would stop clashing with your background.

Comment: Yeah I had seen that, I was hoping something had been added in since. no color is a good point, I'll probably switch to that. Cheers